# Как привильно отловить изменения атрибута в AffterSave?

Tags: yii2

Вот код

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
        if(isset($changedAttributes['parent_id'])){
            $transaction=Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            $this->tree_path=$this->parent_id?$this->parent->tree_path.'.'.$this->id:"$this->id";
            try{
                if(!$this->save()){
                    throw new ErrorException($this->errors);
                }
                $transaction->commit();
            }catch (ErrorException  $ex){
                $transaction->rollBack();
                Yii::error( $ex->getMessage(),$category = 'application');
                return false;
            }
        }
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
```

и вроде отрабатывает но есть одно но если `parent_id` изначально был равен `null` но был изменен то я в `if` не попадаю потому что `$changedAttributes['parent_id']` равно `null`. Как правильно сохранять изменения в модель в случае если изменен атрибут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так работает:

```
array_key_exists('parent_id', $changedAttributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

В Yii2 у AR есть метод [isAttributeChanged](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#isAttributeChanged()-detail), с помощью которого можно проверить, был ли изменен атрибут.

В вашем случае это будет как-то так:

```
    if ($this->isAttributeChanged('parent_id')){
        //...
    }
```

Comment: `isAttributeChanged()` не работает  в `afterSave()`, т.к. после сохранения в `$this->oldAttributes` присваиваются новые значения